# How to recursively remove elements from an XML tree

Tags: xml, algorithm, recursion

I am looking for an efficient algorithm for removing element nodes from an XML tree based on their node name and/or attribute values. In my case, these elements can be stand-alone or not and they can appear anywhere in the tree, so the algorithm needs to recurse over the tree.

There are probably two basic approaches: Either remove elements during a depth-first search or build a new tree during a breadth first search.

Surely, this problem has been solved before. Does anyone have any pointers to where I might find a good generic solution to this problem? I would prefer not to use an XSLT. XPath would be possible, though. 
Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: I would prefer not to use an XSLT => well what technology stack ARE you interested in using .Net, Java, C++, ???

Comment: In [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can just `delete //name` or `delete //*[@attr="val"]`.

Comment: The implementation language is Java with our own XML classes (which don't offer this feature, yet). However, I am looking for an implementation agnostic solution, presuming one exists.